# Django field for storing occurrence rates?

Tags: python, django, usage-statistics

I have a Download model. I would like to store *how often* each instance is being downloaded.

I could just store a count but this seems brutally simplistic. Old files will seem more popular. I could mean-average against the upload date, but this makes newer almost always better. I don't neccessarily want to rank thigns but I'd like to show meaningful data to the people managing the files, something like:

- Last 24 hours
- Last 7 days
- Last 30 days
- Last 365 days
- Total

Is there a field, method, or some sort of generic add-on that I can add to my model to store rate so that I have counts for something like that?

Edit: It occurs to me that doing "last x" means having to somehow store every instance with a datetime until they fall out the end (and only apply to total). I'm open to more efficient slightly compromised solutions that involve less churn.

Comment: If you're dealing with high volume you probably don't want to store this in your regular db. This is basically timeseries data you're generating, you should look at eg [Graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and maybe [django-statsd](https://django-statsd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for some integration

Answer (score 1):

You have not stated how many records / downloads you will be handling but a simple way of doing this create a `DownloadCount` model. Maybe something like:

```
class DownloadCount(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    item_downloaded = models.ForeignKey(Downloads)
```

You will then be able to produce metrics based off of the date field.

Something like:

```
DownloadCount.objects.filter(
    date__range=(state_date, end_date),
    item_downloaded=<Download-Model>
).count()
```

Obviously it would be highly advantageous to cache such results.

If you wanted to make the results a little more accurate you could also add an `IPAddressField` into the model making `DownloadCount` records unique based off of IP Address and Date.

Comment: I guess I could also denormalise out a `total` in my Download model and then delete DownloadCount instances after a year (on a cronjob). Given we're probably talking about tens of thousands, not millions, this might be okay. Still, the idea of storing that much data for the sake of a few pretty stats makes me gurn. Bloody clients.